# Not able to view the Lightning UI desktop

Tags: lightning

I have anabled the Lightning experience on my org with the following settings but still not able to view the Lightning UI. Am I missing any settings that I have to enable? Is it limited to any specific objects since being a beat version?

[image]

Comment: Does your org use PersonAccounts?

Comment: Its just a developer org I created to feel the lightning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_administration) documentation ,you may need to add the lightning experience via permission sets and profiles.

> If you’re in Professional Edition or Group Edition, Lightning Experience is “all or nothing” for you. Once you turn it on, it’s on for all of your users.

If you’re in Enterprise Edition or above, consider these options:

> If you have users with standard profiles, consider moving them to custom profiles, because enabling Lightning Experience auto-enables it for any standard profile users.
>   Create a permission set with the Lightning Experience permission. Apply the permission set directly to the pilot users, then enable Lightning Experience.

Comment: Mine is a developer org created a permission set with Lightning experience permission and assigned it to my profile and I see the lightning desktop UI.

Comment: So you're able to see it?

Comment: Yep I can see it now.

Answer (score -1):

How did you get access to the beta? I am looking to start preparing our Org for the changes, but I wish I had a chance to at least play around with it prior to the release. Let me know!

Comment: Create a new org with the following link.     https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter16-47984592.jsp follow the steps of creating the permission set assign to your user record, enable the lightning any you are there.

Comment: Salesforce updated sandboxes to Winter '16